# Overhead when iterating over 1k+ rows in postgres using peewee

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2, peewee

I'm seen an inexplicably large overhead when iterating over a postgres table.

I profiled the code, and also did a smoke test with `SQLAlchemy` to make sure it wasn't a slow connection or the underlying driver (`psycopg2`).

Running this against a postgres table of ~1M records but fetching only a tiny fraction of that.

```
import time

import peewee
import sqlalchemy
from playhouse import postgres_ext
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL as AlchemyURL
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker as alchemy_sessionmaker

user = 'XXX'
password = 'XXX'
database = 'XXX'
host = 'XXX'
port = 5432

table = 'person'
limit = 1000

peewee_db = postgres_ext.PostgresqlExtDatabase(
    database=database,
    host=host, port=port,
    user=user, password=password,
    use_speedups=True,
    server_side_cursors=True,
    register_hstore=False,
)

alchemy_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(AlchemyURL('postgresql', username=user, password=password,
                                                     database=database, host=host, port=port))
alchemy_session = alchemy_sessionmaker(bind=alchemy_engine)()


class PeeweePerson(peewee.Model):
    class Meta:
        database = peewee_db
        db_table = table

    id = peewee.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=64)
    data = postgres_ext.BinaryJSONField(index=True, index_type='GIN')


class SQLAlchemyPerson(declarative_base()):
    __tablename__ = table

    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = sqlalchemy.Column(JSONB)


def run_raw_query():
    ids = list(peewee_db.execute_sql(f"SELECT id from {table} order by id desc limit {limit}"))
    return ids


def run_peewee_query():
    query = PeeweePerson.select(PeeweePerson.id).order_by(PeeweePerson.id.desc()).limit(limit)
    ids = list(query.tuples())
    return ids


def run_sqlalchemy_query():
    query = alchemy_session.query(SQLAlchemyPerson.id).order_by(sqlalchemy.desc(SQLAlchemyPerson.id)).limit(limit)
    ids = list(query)
    return ids


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t0 = time.time()
    raw_result = run_raw_query()
    t1 = time.time()
    print(f'Raw: {t1 - t0}')

    t2 = time.time()
    sqlalchemy_result = run_sqlalchemy_query()
    t3 = time.time()
    print(f'SQLAlchemy: {t3 - t2}')

    t4 = time.time()
    peewee_result = run_peewee_query()
    t5 = time.time()
    print(f'peewee: {t5 - t4}')

    assert raw_result == sqlalchemy_result == peewee_result
```

- With limit = 1000:

  Raw: 0.02643609046936035
  SQLAlchemy: 0.03697466850280762
  peewee: 1.0509874820709229
- With limit = 10000

  Raw: 0.15931344032287598
  SQLAlchemy: 0.07229042053222656
  peewee: 10.82826042175293

Both examples use server side cursors.

I briefly profiled this, and looks like 95%+ of the time is spent calling `cursor.fetchone` https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/d8e34b0682d87bd56c1a3636445d9c0fccf2b1e2/peewee.py#L2340

Any idea whats up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be related to an inefficiency in the implementation of server-side cursors in Peewee 2.x. Specifically, I think it's because peewee's cursor wrapper uses the .fetchone() db-api rather than fetching many rows. 3.0a has a new implementation which ought to be faster: https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/commit/0ae17c519475c935d9db3c338f36ef058a3f879c

Furthermore, using client-side cursors in 2.x has none of these efficiency problems so that can be used as a workaround for the time being.